# Compare two different lists

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I have rephased my message with explicit question.

I have two different list.

```
List<Car> car = GetCars();
List<int> carListNumber = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3};

public Car
{
    public int number
    public string color
    public string brand
}
```

**My request is to achieve a new Car list that shall contain number 1,2,3 based on LinQ coding?**

In order to get this specific car you have to recieve right car number from carListNumber.

Comment: How do you determine which cars/numbers you want?

Comment: I make this version more easier for end user and I will make some complementory of the rest... If problem occur, I won't have mind to add another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Need to have a list of the number 1, 2
>   and 3 from Car's number based on LinQ
>   or similiar.
>
> How shall I do to compare two
>   different list with different context?

So you want to take a car from the list, say BMW, and find out it's number?

I really struggle to understand quite what you want to do. You can address a List with an index. Will that help?

EDIT out the below:

Finally understood what you want to do. Do you want the order of cars to be driving, or the order of numbers? If you have BMW2, Audi1, do you want the number order to be 2, 1, or the car order to be Audi, BMW. Then I will help with the code :)

```
List<Car> car1 = GetCars1();
int number = car1.IndexOf(//car//);
```

If you need any more help, can you please re-explain your question, and also, could you please do us a big favour, and mark/up-vote suitable answers in your previous questions.

Thanks so much!

Comment: I have rephrased my message more explicity. Please inform me if any changes needed. 
Sincerely,
Fullmetalboy

Answer (score 5):

```
carListNumber.SequenceEquals(car1.Select(car=>car.number));
```

Comment: Linq is a great way of ding in one line what others can do in 12 :)  Good solution

Answer (score 0):

To get a List<int> of the cars numbers from the List<Car> try the following:

```
var listOfCarNumbers = car1.Select(car=>car.number).ToList();
var listsMatches = listOfCarNumbers.TrueForAll(carListNumber.Contains) && listOfCarNumbers.TrueForAll(carListNumber.Contains);
```

ListsMatches then contains a boolean value if the 2 match.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool listsAreTheSame(List<Car> cars, List<int> numbers){
  if(cars.Count() != numbers.Count())
    return false;
  for(int  i = 0; i < cars.Count(); i++){
    if(cars[i].number != numbers[i])
      return false;
    }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: you should look into LINQ - this can be done in a far more concise manner using some LINQ extension methods.

Comment: I know my LINQ well, but I've just woken up, so this was all I could put together with my fuzzy thinking at the moment :-)